# create valid json data using for loop

Tags: jquery

I want to create a Json data in Jquery.

For that iam doing like this.Iam getting error inplace of  `"customParam'+i+'Key:"`

```
var counter=4;
var data;
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){                 
             data = {
               "Param'+i+'Key:" : $('#key' + i).val(),
               "Param'+i+'Value:" : $('#value' + i).val()    
            }; 
    }
```

After performing loop operations my data will be

```
data={
             "Param1Key": testkey
             "Param1Value": ttestval
             "Param2Key":testkey
             "Param2Value": testval
             "Param3Key":testkey
             "Param3Value": ...
             "Param4Key":...
             "Param4Value": ...

};
```

also i want to append  `"job": $('#job').val(),"names": $('#names').val()` to `data`.How it is possible???

my resulting data will be likes below

data={

```
             "job": $('#job').val(),
             "names": $('#names').val(),
             "Param1Key": testkey,
             "Param1Value": ttestval,
             "Param2Key":testkey,
             "Param2Value": testval,
             "Param3Key":testkey,
             "Param3Value": ...,
             "Param4Key":...,
             "Param4Value": ...,

};


$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/save",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is simply a text format to represent a JavaScript object.  When building an object for submitting to the AJAX function you do not need to use JSON.

The dataType parameter of the AJAX function refers to the type of data you expect to be returned from the server.  That is where JSON comes in.

You can create the struct first and then while looping add the values to it as an associative array.

```
var counter=4;
var data = {};
    for(var i=1; i<counter; i++){                 
          data["Param"+i+"Key"] = $('#key' + i).val();
          data["Param"+i+"Value"]= $('#value' + i).val();
    } 
data.job = $('#job').val();
data.names = $('#names').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data` has to be like this.  **Either single quotes or double quotes**.

```
"Param"+i+"Key:" : $('#key' + i).val(),
"Param"+i+"Value:" : $('#value' + i).val()
```

To **append**, try like this

```
data.job = $('#jobid').val();  
data.names = $('#names').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going.

```
var data = {
    "job": $('#job').val(),
    "names": $('#names').val()
};
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    data["Param" + i + "Key"] = $('#key' + i).val();
    data["Param" + i + "Value"] = $('#value' + i).val();
} 
// Do things with data here
```